# quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url for both testing and localhost development

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I'm developing a Quarkus app with Keycloak for OIDC (OpenID Connect). During development, the app is running at `localhost:8080` while Keycloak is running locally as well using Docker.

`application.properties`:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8484/auth/realms/my-sso
```

This is working fine.

**Now I want to create some tests.** https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect#wiremock told me to update `application.properties` as follows:

```
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=${keycloak.url}/auth/realms/my-sso
```

My question: How do I set that value *only* for testing. I don't want to keep toggling the values by commenting/uncommenting. If it's dictated by profile, what profiles to use?

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration_profiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an application properties file in the test resource folder. It will be used only for tests:

```
src/test/resources/application.properties
```